# Reading a Map<String, Integer> from configmap.yaml in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, configmap

I have added a map in my values.yaml like below

```yaml
journey:
  event:
    range:
      abc: 45
```

I read the above entry in my configmap.yaml as below

```yaml
journey.event.range: |
    {{ .Values.patientjourney.event.timelinerange | toYaml | nindent 4 }}
```

I am trying to read this entry as a map in Spring Boot application via `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "journey.event")
public class JourneyViewConfig {

    private Map<String, Integer> range = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Integer> getRange() {
        return range;
    }

    public void setRange(String configValue) {
        this.range = parseConfigValue(configValue);
    }

    private Map<String, Integer> parseConfigValue(String configValue) {
        Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

        if (configValue == null || configValue.trim().isEmpty()) {
            return resultMap;
        }

        String[] lines = configValue.trim().split("\\r?\\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            String[] keyValue = line.split(":");
            if (keyValue.length == 2) {
                String key = keyValue[0].trim();
                Integer value = Integer.parseInt(keyValue[1].trim());
                resultMap.put(key, value);
            }
        }

        return resultMap;
    }

}
```

My ConfigMap structure is as below

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: configmap
data:
  key1: 'true'
  key2: {{ printf "https://%s.%s" .Values.env.xxx .Values.env.abc }}
  key3: "2020-10-08T00:00:00.0+00:00"
  journey:
    event:
      range:
         {{ .Values.journey.event.erange | toYaml | nindent 4 }}
```

As seen there is a dirty logic converting string to Map, as configmap entry is read as a string, is there a cleaner way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 0):

Spring already knows how to read map-typed properties; see the Spring Boot documentation on [Type-Safe Configuration Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties) for example.  If you remove the setter and just have

```java
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "journey.event")
public class JourneyViewConfig {
    private Map<String, Integer> range = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Integer> getRange() {
        return range;
    }
}
```

then Spring knows that a property `journey.event.range.abc` needs to set an `abc` key in the `Map` returned by `getRange()`.

Correspondingly, when you write out your ConfigMap, you should make sure a normal YAML map gets written.  Do not use the YAML `|` syntax to write a multi-line string for the property value, directly write YAML syntax.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata: { ... }
data:
  application.yml: |
    journey:
      event:
        range:
{{ .Values.patientjourney.event.timelinerange | toYaml | indent 10 }}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , but I am using helm template in config.yaml and adding suggested fix breaks with error

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: YAML parse error on configmap.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 21: did not find expected key

Comment: Added configmap for reference in main question

Comment: `helm template --debug` will print out the template output, even if it doesn't parse as YAML.  It's not clear how the ConfigMap in the question relates to the specific Spring properties you discuss.

Comment: Have updated question and added how I am adding entry in CM but parser complains

Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(ConfigMap.data.journey): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.ConfigMap.data: got "map", expected "string"

Comment: The keys in a ConfigMap `data:` need to have string values.  You cannot embed arbitrary nested Spring config YAML in one.  In my last example, I've created a ConfigMap key `application.yml` with a string value (the line ends with a `|` YAML multi-line string indicator) and embedded the configuration in that.

Comment: aah I got you , let me try that

Comment: Still I see its read as a string and not as a map by spring boot

Reason: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer>]